# Best way to filter the value in Mysql-PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select box in my PHP & mysql code like.

```
<select id="addressbook_user" name ="addressbook_user">
<option value="hi">hi</option>
<option value="hello">hello</option>
<option value="newa">newa</option>

<select>
```

I am storing the selected value in a jQuery list and i am passing that list to the php code to filter the other options except list items like.

```
$list = $_GET['list'];

print $list;
print_r($list);
$query = "SELECT *  from demo_addressbook WHERE user_created_id IN(SELECT id FROM demo_user WHERE user_name = '$get_user_name') AND type = 1 AND guest_name NOT IN '$list' ";                               
$sresult    = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

and based on the result i am trying to create the latest select box without selected value of the list .

but unfortunately my above query is not working

```
hiYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'hi' at line 1 is the error .
```

Please suggest me the best way to filter the array data from a mysql table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the variable with `parenthesis`

```
NOT IN ('$list')
```

Comment: working fine for first filtering for second again it is showing all data

Answer (score 0):

Please Change below sql , bacause value of variable is not found and In
    statement is required lile " columnName in('','')":

```
$query = "SELECT *  from demo_addressbook WHERE
 user_created_id IN(SELECT id FROM demo_user 
 WHERE user_name = '" . $get_user_name . "')
 AND (type = 1) AND guest_name NOT IN(". $list .") ";
```